# A jQuery function within media query not firing as expected

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I am learning jQuery. I am using a media query. When I shrink the browser window all of the code responds as expected except for my nested function (that starts with `$( "tr" ).each(function() {`).

If I shrink the window *and* refresh the page, the nested function *does* fire as expected.

How can I get everything to fire *without* refreshing the page?

```
function myFunction(x) {
  if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
    $( "tbody tr" ).wrapInner( "<label class='wrapper'></label>" );
    $( ".overdueTicket" ).closest( "tr" ).addClass( "overdue" );
    $( ".paperclip" ).closest( "tr" ).addClass( "paperclip-icon" );
    $( ".paperclip-icon td.osta_ticket" ).append( "<div class='ticket-has-attachement' data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' data-original-title='<?php echo __('Ticket Has Attachment'); ?>'>&nbsp;</div>" );
    $( "tr" ).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $href = $this.find( ".pull-right "),
            $target = $this.find( "td.osta_ticket" );
        $href.appendTo($target);
    });
  } else {
    $("tbody tr > .wrapper").contents().unwrap();
    $('.overdueTicket').closest('tr').removeClass("overdue");
    $('.paperclip').closest('tr').removeClass("paperclip-icon");
  }
}
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 760px)")
myFunction(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(myFunction) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Comment: I believe the function is being triggered correctly... check if `$this`, `$href` and `$target` variables are getting the desired value, also why are you creating variables with `$`, it's not required and in the case of `$this` may be overwriting the context variable...

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DIEGOCARRASCAL. I entered `$this` in the console and discovered that it already in use elsewhere: `k.fn.init [div#alert.dialog]`. As an experiment I rewrote the code replacing `$this` with `$test`: `var $test = $(this),
   $href = $test.find( ".pull-right"),
   $target = $test.find( "td.osta_ticket" );
  $href.appendTo($target);`. It seems to now work perfectly, although when I enter `$test` into console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $test is not defined`. I *did* mention I'm a complete n00b, yeah?

Comment: `$this` is a reference to the scope of "execution" so probably it was failing silently and just avoiding the assign operation. On the other hand, `$test` only exist during the execution of the code, after the variable gets destroyed and the scope goes to your page and it's events (like click), anyway, I'm happy it helps you.